# PIL draw.text() is displaying string containing arabic ligature as two separate glyphs

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, arabic-support

I have python code. "کم" is a string, consisting of two alphabets ک and م .
but they are combined in arabic.  i am giving this word to PIL library function. But it is saving image separately both alphabets. How can i combine them.?

```
data2= "کم"    
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2),data2,(0,0,0),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("abc"+".png")
```

output:
that is ک and م .

Comment: Did you not see? they are combined already. why draw is not printing as it is.  if you have some solution(function, etc) please tell me about it, to pass in it .

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have deleted my previous comment. No, I know of no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the python_arabic_reshaper library in order to get the text correctly written. This is the [github](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper) repo for this library.

Install the library:

```
pip install --upgrade arabic-reshaper
```

Then import it like this:

```
import arabic_reshaper
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
text_to_be_reshaped = 'اللغة العربية رائعة'
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)
```